# Send command and a argument to python socket server

Tags: python

Im currently setting up a **server** with the following while:

```
try:
    while 1:
        #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print time.ctime() + ' Connection from: ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
        #start new thread takes 1st argument as a function name to be run, second is the tuple of arguments to the function.
        start_new_thread(shreddingclient ,(conn,))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Exiting gracefully anyway"
finally:
    s.close()
```

And i was thinking it would be nice too be able to send a command, and argument to the server, the `def shredding client`.

I have googled, a lot, and have found something like this on the **client side**:

```
def send_data(self, com, arg):
       content={"command": com, "arg": arg}
       return json.dumps(content)
```

## My question:

How will `def shreddingclient` look like to accept commands, an argument to execute other `def`s?

(This is to avoid that `shreddingclient` will be a huge `if`/`elif` function)

Comment: What kind of argument are you thinking about? The name of a function? Data?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are only asking about dispatching commands once they've been received and decoded from `json` into a `dict`, you can use use another `dict` to map command names to the functions that implement them. Here, `msg` is the decoded message `dict` that was passed to shredderclient

```
def command1(msg):
    print(msg['arg'])

def command2(msg):
    print(msg['arg'])

dispatch_table = {'command1':command1, 'command2':command2}

def process_message(msg):
    try:
        cmd = dispatch_table[msg['command']]
    except KeyError:
        print('invalid command')
        return None
    cmd(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a dispatcher, a quick example would look like:

```
dispatcher = {'command_1': func_1,
              'command_2': func_2,
              ...}
```

and as you receive data:

```
data = json.loads(content)
command = data['command']
args, kwargs = data['args'], data['kwargs']
try:
    res = dispatcher[command](*args, **kwargs)
except KeyError:
    print "Unknown command"
```